# Prevent Bootstrap collapse from collapsing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap collapse with a button inside the header. On the button is clickEvent.

I want to prevent the collapseEvent when clicking the button. Does anyone have a tip?

This does not help here

```js
$('#buttonId').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    // some action ...
});
```

Is there a way to prevent the default collapse action?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are looking for  `stopPropagation()` method instead:

```
$('#buttonId').live("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();   
    // some action ...
});
```

If your button is a link  (`<a>` tag ), you should prevent default too or use `return false;`

BTW, live is deprecated, you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegation syntax instead, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonId', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    // some action ...
});
```

Comment: Hey @roasted,  
thanks for this! Works great!  

I think in my case a simple click event is enough. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @chris Ya, if your button element is already in DOM when you set click handler, there is no reason to use delegation. Then a simple click handler would be better

Answer (score 0):

StopPropagation(), PreventDefault() don't stop the event from reaching the accordion button. You need to set/unset the collapse property like so:

(this I do in mouse down & cancel)

```
$("button.accordion-button").attr("data-bs-toggle", "collapse");
```

(this I do in mouse move, eg, if scrolling)

```
$("button.accordion-button").attr("data-bs-toggle", "non-collapsing");
```

collapse keeps the state of the accordion button eg. open/closed.

**Example is for Bootstrap 5**

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue.

In case somebody needs to solve it using proper JavaScript, you can use the code below.

It precisely focuses on the anchor tag, avoiding any disruption to the default collapse events of the Bootstrap Accordion.

As stated on the official Bootstrap documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/accordion/), to render an accordion that expanded, we need to add the `.show` class on the `.accordion-collapse` element, drop the `.collapsed` class from the `.accordion-button` element and set its `aria-expanded` attribute to `true`.

`HTML`

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
<!--    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="handleAccordionClick('https://www.google.com/')">GOOGLE</a> -->
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample" style="">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the item's accordion body.</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`JavaScript`

```
function handleAccordionClick(url) {
    // Navigate to the specified URL
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
var accordionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-button");
for (var i = 0; i < accordionButtons.length; i++) {
    var anchorTag = accordionButtons[i].querySelector('a');
    anchorTag.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var currentAccordionButton = this.parentElement;
        var ariaControls = currentAccordionButton.getAttribute("aria-controls");
        // var headerAccordion = currentAccordionButton.parentElement;
        // var containerAccordion = headerAccordion.parentElement;
        // var accordionDiv = containerAccordion.querySelector("#" + ariaControls);
        var accordionDiv = document.querySelector("#" + ariaControls);
        accordionDiv.classList.add("show");
        currentAccordionButton.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
        currentAccordionButton.classList.remove("collapsed");
    });
}
```