# Cancel/prevent Bootstrap5 collapse when clicking inside links/buttons

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a table with parent rows, that have hidden child rows. These child rows are shown/hidden using the bootstrap collapse mechanic. Clicking on the parent row toggles the collapse on the child rows. Parent rows and their childs can be dynamically created.

Parent rows can contain links and buttons. I want to cancel/prevent the collapse toggle when clicking on these. A simple minimum example is given below.

A similar question was asked here: [stackoverflow - prevent bootstrap collapse from collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914747/prevent-bootstrap-collapse-from-collapsing)

The `event.stopPropgation();` does not seem to work (see below), not even when targeting the link/button directly (which anyway probably won't help with dynamically created elements).

I've tried to listen to the [collapse events from Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#events) and use the `.toggle()` method to undo the collapse, but this (obviously) leads to a recursive event.

Is there a simple method to prevent the links/buttons inside the collapse-triggering row from toggling the collapse?

```js
$("#createNewRow").on("click", function() {
    var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000);
  new_row = `
    <tr data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".row`+number+`-child">
        <td>
        This is a dynamically created parent row. Click me to toggle childs.
        <a class="child-link" href="!#">A Link!</a>
        <button class="child-button">A button!</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr class="collapse child row`+number+`-child"><td>I'm a child row!</td></tr>
  <tr class="collapse child row`+number+`-child"><td>I'm another child row!</td></tr>
  <tr class="collapse child row`+number+`-child"><td>I'm yet another child row!</td></tr>
  `;
  $("#main-table").append(new_row);
});

$(".child-link").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("The link was clicked!");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".child-button").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("The button was clicked!");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", ".child-link", function(e) {
    console.log("The link was clicked!");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", ".child-button", function(e) {
    console.log("The button was clicked!");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
tr {
  background-color: #fcf;
}

.child {
  background-color: #efd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="w-100" id="main-table">
  <tr data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".row1-child">
    <td>
      This is a parent row. Click me to toggle childs.
      <a class="child-link" href="!#">A Link!</a>
      <button class="child-button">A button!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="collapse child row1-child"><td>I'm a child row!</td></tr>
  <tr class="collapse child row1-child"><td>I'm another child row!</td></tr>
  <tr class="collapse child row1-child"><td>I'm yet another child row!</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button class="mt-4" id="createNewRow">Create a new set of rows!</button>
```

Comment: The minimum example belongs directly inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform like jsfiddle. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the remark, I've added the example to the question.

Comment: I’m guessing it might be easier if you don’t trigger the functionality automatically via the `data-` attributes, but handle it yourself, doing the collapse toggling via the available JS functions, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#methods If you combine that with a click handler for the table rows that you want to use as triggers, you should be able to check the event target before doing the actual toggle.

Comment: That's a good idea! I've implemented that for now and it works well. Still would be nicer to have this directly working with the bootstrap attributes.

Comment: You have a bit of a special situation here, because you have basically “nested” _interactive_ elements here. Bootstrap normally uses `a` or `button` for the trigger element - in which you could not place any additional interactive elements to begin with, HTML simply forbids that. You “worked around” that by using `tr` as the trigger element instead - not an interactive element by default, so HTML rules _allow_ this, […]

Comment: […] but in the end the effect is the same - clickable elements inside other clickable elements, which is not the best idea regarding accessibility to begin with. So I guess you have to live with Bootstrap not supporting this out-of-the-box, because it is simply too much of a special case. (And speaking of accessibility, might be a good idea to add `tabindex` to those table rows, so they can at least be reached using keyboard navigation.)

Comment: Please accept the answer so others now the question is solved!

Answer (score 1):

This is very good question! The propagation of events is tricky,

You need to *conditionally* assign an event handler that prevents the Bootstrap collapse events (`show` and `hide`) from occurring. The Collapse event will *only* occur when the parent `tr` is clicked.

```
var eventHandler = function (e) {
     console.log("The collapse event was prevented!", e);
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
}

// initially prevent collapse from toggling
$(".row1-child").on("show.bs.collapse", eventHandler)

// prevent the click event on child links
$(".child-link").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("The link was clicked!");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

// prevent the click event on child buttons
$(".child-button").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("The button was clicked!");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

// when the parent row is clicked manually toggle the collapsible elements and re-attach event listeners
$("[data-bs-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {    
    console.log("The parent was clicked! dispatch");
    $(".row1-child").off("show.bs.collapse", eventHandler)
    $(".row1-child").off("hide.bs.collapse", eventHandler)
    $(".row1-child").collapse('toggle')
    $(".row1-child").on("show.bs.collapse", eventHandler)
    $(".row1-child").on("hide.bs.collapse", eventHandler)
});
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/zyWBNSaRqD#)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried the Demo and I think this does not work on dynamically created rows. Also, is there a reason for using both .stopPropagation() and .preventDefault()?

Comment: "I think this does not work on dynamically created rows" .. yes which is outside the scope of your question. Add the click handlers once the rows are created in "createNewRow"