# Bootstrap Collapse this ul items onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Have Html Code like this :

```
<div style="padding-right: 12px;">
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li class="menu-item active" onclick="onMenuClick(this)">
            <i class="fa-duotone fa-house-chimney"></i>
            پیشخوان
        </li>
        <li accessibility="edit_or_add_product" class="menu-item">
            <i onclick="onMenuClick(this)" class="fa-duotone fa-compass"></i>
            موقعیت
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#cRequestMenu"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="cRequestMenu">
            <i class="fa-duotone fa-code-pull-request-draft"></i>
            مدیریت درخواست ها
            <ul class="menu-items collapse" id="cRequestMenu">
                <li class="menu-item" onclick="onMenuClick(this)">
                    <i class="fa-duotone fa-arrow-progress"></i>
                    پیگیری درخواست
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" onclick="onMenuClick(this)"><i class="fa-duotone fa-people-pants"></i>جمعیت</li>

        <li class="menu-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#cMenuSystem" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="cMenuSystem">
            <i class="fa-duotone fa-server"></i>
            سیستم
            <ul class="menu-items collapse" id="cMenuSystem">
                <li class="menu-item" onclick="openLink('Application/Log/log4j2' , this)">
                    <i class="fa-duotone fa-bug"></i>
                    لاگ / دیباگ
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item" onclick="onMenuClick(this)">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
            خروج از سیستم
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

and js like this :

```
function openLink(href, elm) {
    window.open(href, '_blank').focus();
    onMenuClick(elm);
}

function onMenuClick(elm) {
    let menu_items = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
    for (let i = 0; i < menu_items.length; ++i) {
        menu_items[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    elm.classList.add("active");


}
```

The result of my Code its here as Gif:
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Zqr.gif)

What I need is after click on Expanded UL item the expanded not going to Callops! and user sees what them clicked.
in the other explation :what I want is user if expand the list and click on item the item shows active and not close the list.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065160/cancel-prevent-bootstrap5-collapse-when-clicking-inside-links-buttons) answer your question?

Comment: It dosent seems to be right and I don't think its good for ul list. that have multiple list.